# Will declaring the same var over and over in Swift build memory?

Tags: ios, swift, variables, memory

I'm coding in swift and am curious as to how the variables will work if I declare them either inside of a loop that iterates or outside of a loop.

Example 1:

```
loop {

  var x = 1

  do something with x

}
```

Example 2:

```
var x = 1

loop {

  do something with x

}
```

Will the first one keep creating things that reference x?  Or are the two not going to be any different in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example 1:

keep alloc variable x and dealloc variable x each loop. Eachone has the same value but different pointer.

You can process the same VALUE each loop.But you can't access the x outside the loop.

Example 2:
At the beginning  of each loop , the x's value may changed.

You process the same POINTER each loop.And  you can access the x outside the loop.

Comment: What is the difference in memory, if any?  Will processing a new pointer every time in the first one result in memory being built up?

Comment: No. memory will not built up. Have a look at this wiki on Automatic variable:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable

Answer (score 1):

Example 1:

```
    loop {

      var x = anyobject

      do something with x

    }
```

create x and then release x each loop

Example 2:

```
var x = anyobject

loop {

   do something with x

}
```

x inside the loop has the same memory with x outside the loop. Doesn't create/release each loop or end of the loop

Comment: I'm assuming it's the same case if X were say, an UIImage or something like an object?

Comment: Do you mean x = object?

Comment: Declaring X as a UIImage